# output of for loop as a matrix MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop, output

the following function gives as output a 3x3 matrix

```
S=myfunction(i,3)
```

I would like to know please if there is a way to stock the output of the following loop in a way that I can recall the matrix from each step.

```
 for i=1:8
 S=myfunction(i,3)
 end
```

This loop at each step gives a different matrix and I would like to give a name to each matrix from each step for exampe S1, S2 , S3 ..

Is this possible? or should I save the result in a 3 x (24) huge matrix?

Thank you

example of output:

```
 for i=1:8
 S=myinfluence(i,3)
 end

 S = 

'HH'    'HH'    'HH'
'HH'    'HH'    'HH'
'HH'    'HH'    'HH'
```

Comment: there are higer dimensional matrices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way seems to me is to have a three dimensional matrix, and just index along the third dimension to save the intermediate result.

```
for i = 1:8
  S(:, :, i) = myinfluence(i,3);
end
```

then you can access each iteration by calling  `S(:, : , 1)` or `S(:, : , 2)` or `S(:, : , 3)` and so on.

using the `:` as an index means that all of the entries along the appropriate index of the right hand side of assignment will be  automatically copied to the corresponding index in the left hand side of assignment.